# Сборщик мусора и HandleCollector

Tags: c#, .net

Почитал про `HandleCollector`, который можно использовать в сценариях работы с неуправляемыми ресурсами.

Так вот, что произойдет если в HandleCollector будет превышен искусственный предел кол-ва ресурсов, но все ресурсы будут достижимыми?

Сборщик мусора сойдет с ума и будет очень часто вызывать сборку, что скажется на производительности?